# html5 validation not showing after submit

Tags: javascript, html, angular, validation

im struggling to find out why tooltip/message bubble from html5 validation is not showed "on" checkbox when I press submit button but it is shown when I hover mouse over it? It seems to happen on Chrome/Edge. On Firefox works fine.

In code I used ngNativeValidate attribute:

```
<form ngNativeValidate autocomplete="off" (ngSubmit)="click_MoveToNextView()" #form="ngForm">
```

Input:

```
<input type="checkbox" required>
```

Submit:

```
<input type='submit'></input>
```

Code with similar issue ():
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ro0a2fcu/1/)

Please anyone?

Comment: I checked and it did show.

Comment: @MahdiJoon You are using chrome?

Comment: no I'm in firefox